# Is there any possibility to work around the transitive closure used in interface inheritance?

Tags: c#, interface, multiple-inheritance

Using interface inheritance, I would like to have **all** items from **all** ancestors in terminal interface/class <s>and I also would like to have a **base interface** for all derived interfaces/objects (inheritance tree root) for general object processing like `Process(IBase b)`</s>. So, for example, instead of this:

```
public interface IBase 
{
    Guid Id {get;} 
    void SwitchOn();
}

public interface IPart1 : IBase {void DoPart1Specific();}
public interface IPart2 : IBase {void DoPart2Specific();}
public interface ICompound1 : IPart1, IPart2 {}

public class Compound : ICompound1
{
    public Guid Id => Guid.Empty;        // IBase
    public void SwitchOn() {}            // IBase
    public void DoPart1Specific() {}     // IPart1
    public void DoPart2Specific() {}     // IPart2
}
```

I would like to have something like this (using pseudo-explicit-interface-implementation notation *which of course won't work here*):

```
public class Compound : ICompound1
{
    Guid Part1.Id => Guid.Empty;         // ICompound1.IPart1
    void Part1.SwitchOn() {}             // ICompound1.IPart1
    void DoPart1Specific() {}            // ICompound1.IPart1

    Guid Part2.Id => Guid.Empty;         // ICompound1.IPart2
    void Part2.SwitchOn() {}             // ICompound1.IPart2
    void DoPart2Specific() {}            // ICompound1.IPart2
}
```

Only not-so-nice and partial solution I'm able to figure out is to replicate all the common stuff in each interface definition, which is too verbose and error prone (in this case the explicit implementation works and let's say it does not matter that the `Compound` class members can't be public)<s>, but there is no base interface available</s> )o:

```
public interface IPart1Ex
{
    Guid Id {get;} 
    void SwitchOn();
    void DoPart1Specific();
}

public interface IPart2Ex
{
    Guid Id {get;} 
    void SwitchOn();
    void DoPart2Specific();
}

public interface ICompound1Ex : IPart1Ex, IPart2Ex {}

public class CompoundEx : ICompound1Ex
{
    Guid IPart1Ex.Id => Guid.Empty;
    void IPart1Ex.SwitchOn() {}
    void IPart1Ex.DoPart1Specific() {}

    Guid IPart2Ex.Id => Guid.Empty;
    void IPart2Ex.SwitchOn() {}
    void IPart2Ex.DoPart2Specific() {}
}
```

Comment: You say you want to do "for general object processing like `Process(IBase b)`" but, say you call `Process(new Compound())` - how is `Process` meant to know that `IBase` has been implemented twice (or more) and perform all processing using all implementations?

Comment: That's a very good question which brings some darkness to my plans... I will try to project it to real situation.

Comment: Removing that mentioned requirement. Even in thinking in C++ allowing multiple inheritance I wouldn't be able to tell whether it is even possible or makes sense for the real scenario. Will try to rethink the complete problem and maybe introduce some more composition instead of multiple interfacing...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you don't want to inherit from interfaces at all, but rather use composition. Your Compound class needs to hold an instance for Part1 and an instance for Part2. This would give something like:

```
public interface IPart {
    Guid Id { get; }
    void SwitchOn();
    void Execute();
}

public class Compound
{
    private readonly IPart _part1;
    private readonly IPart _part2;

    public Compound(IPart part1, IPart part2)
    {
        _part1 = part1;
        _part2 = part2;
    }

    public Guid Part1Id { get { return _part1.Id; } }
    public void Part1SwitchOn() { _part1.SwitchOn(); }
    public void DoPart1Specific() { _part1.Execute(); }

    public Guid Part2Id { get { return _part2.Id; } }
    public void Part2SwitchOn() { _part2.SwitchOn(); }
    public void DoPart2Specific() { _part2.Execute(); }
}
```

Or a simpler class would just be:

```
public class Compound
{
    public Compound(IPart part1, IPart part2)
    {
        Part1 = part1;
        Part2 = part2;
    }

    public IPart Part1 { get; private set; }
    public IPart Part2 { get; private set; }
}
```

and then access them in the calling code using:

```
var compound = MyMethodWhichCreatesCompound();
var id1 = compound.Part1.Id;
compound.Part2.Execute();
//etc
```

Comment: Yes, for the given example, the composition is the best one. There were two consecutively evolving contradictive requirements and the composite objects I used in the example were the more tricky part of the whole system. Next time I will think it twice before posting confusing question ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I think using the `new` keyword on interface member definitions can help you:

```
public interface IBase 
{
    Guid Id {get;} 
    void SwitchOn();
}

public interface IPart1 : IBase
{
    new Guid Id {get;}
    new void SwitchOn();
    void DoPart1Specific();
}

public interface IPart2 : IBase
{
    new Guid Id {get;}
    new void SwitchOn();
    void DoPart2Specific();
}
```